# how to access file from google drive in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

i am trying to read data from from google drive but it is giving error that file is not found

i tried it using below code snipet:

```
# Load the Drive helper and mount
from google.colab import drive

# This will prompt for authorization.
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from pandas import read_hdf
df_final_train = read_hdf('FB_data/storage_sample_stage5.h5', 'train_df',mode='r')
df_final_test = read_hdf('FB_data/storage_sample_stage5.h5', 'test_df',mode='r')
```

error is

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 from pandas import read_hdf
----> 2 df_final_train = read_hdf('FB_data/storage_sample_stage5.h5', 'train_df',mode='r')
      3 df_final_test = read_hdf('FB_data/storage_sample_stage5.h5', 'test_df',mode='r')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, **kwargs)
    379         if not exists:
    380             raise FileNotFoundError(
--> 381                 "File {path} does not exist".format(path=path_or_buf)
    382             )
    383

FileNotFoundError: File FB_data/storage_sample_stage5.h5 does not exist

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`/content/drive` is not the working directory.

Use `%cd` to change the working directory to your Drive root. Or, use absolute paths in your arguments to `read_hdf`.

Comment: how to get absolute path